# Spring Boot 2.3.3 SOAP Web Service WS Security Compilation Issue

Tags: spring-boot, maven, ws-security

I'm trying to secure my SOAP Web Service using User name and password but after adding ws security is not compilng with below error

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'annotationActionEndpointMapping' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/ws/config/annotation/DelegatingWsConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.ws.soap.addressing.server.AnnotationActionEndpointMapping]: Factory method 'annotationActionEndpointMapping' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'securityInterceptor' defined in class path resource [com/user/sms/WebServiceConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.ws.soap.security.xwss.XwsSecurityInterceptor]: Factory method 'securityInterceptor' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/xml/wss/XWSSecurityException
   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:655) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
```

this is complete POM

```
...
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
...     <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>wsdl4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>wsdl4j</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-ws-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
...
```

WebServiceConfig

```
@Configuration
@EnableWs
public class WebServiceConfig extends WsConfigurerAdapter {
    @Bean
    public XwsSecurityInterceptor securityInterceptor() {
        XwsSecurityInterceptor securityInterceptor = new XwsSecurityInterceptor();
        securityInterceptor.setCallbackHandler(callbackHandler());
        securityInterceptor.setPolicyConfiguration(new ClassPathResource("securityPolicy.xml"));
        return securityInterceptor;
    }

    @Bean
    public SimplePasswordValidationCallbackHandler callbackHandler() {
        SimplePasswordValidationCallbackHandler callbackHandler = new SimplePasswordValidationCallbackHandler();
        callbackHandler.setUsersMap(Collections.singletonMap("admin", "pwd123"));
        return callbackHandler;
    }
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will make it works

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-ws-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.wss</groupId>
            <artifactId>xws-security</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.xml.crypto</groupId>
                    <artifactId>xmldsig</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
                    <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
```